# Website not opening with chrome driver but opening with geckodriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, geckodriver

I am trying to scrape the website. First of all, it is not working with Beautifulsoup but when I am trying to open it with selenium chrome driver it's not opening. It's opening with firefox but it's very slow and gives an error on element click. Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
opt.add_argument("--disable-xss-auditor")
opt.add_argument("--disable-web-security")
opt.add_argument("--allow-running-insecure-content")
opt.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
opt.add_argument("--disable-setuid-sandbox")
opt.add_argument("--disable-webgl")
opt.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get(f"http://app1.nmpa.gov.cn/data_nmpa/face3/base.jsp?tableId=25&tableName=TABLE25&title=%B9%FA%B2%FA%D2%A9%C6%B7&bcId=152904713761213296322795806604&CbSlDlH0=qGrYrAktn7.tn7.tnznJalIvVetjcXpaapSdKuqmmoVqqWL")
```

Comment: I think you need

`driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=opt)`

rather than

`driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())`

Answer (score 0):

Possibly *Selenium* driven *ChromeDriver* initiated [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) *Browsing Context* is [geting detected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62520191/7429447) as [bot](/questions/tagged/bot) and the *`arguments`* you have added can't bypass the bot detection mechanism effectively.

---

### Solution

You can evade the detection by adding a few *`arguments`* and *`experimental_option`* as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
s = Service('C:\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
driver.get("http://app1.nmpa.gov.cn/data_nmpa/face3/base.jsp?tableId=25&tableName=TABLE25&title=%B9%FA%B2%FA%D2%A9%C6%B7&bcId=152904713761213296322795806604&CbSlDlH0=qGrYrAktn7.tn7.tnznJalIvVetjcXpaapSdKuqmmoVqqWL")
```